# Running SQLite query in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I am new to SQLite queries in android. Trying to run a query. However, app keeps crashing with the following error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col
>   -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Below is the extract of Code

```
public String getOutputData(){
    String inputData = "'Vineet'";

    Cursor cursorNew = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM groupseries INNER JOIN email " +
            "ON groupseries.emailid = email._id INNER JOIN user ON " +
            "groupseries.userid = user._id WHERE name=" + inputData, null);
    cursorNew.moveToFirst ();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    while(cursorNew.moveToNext()){
        int index1 = cursorNew.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME);
        int index2 = cursorNew.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_EMAIL);
        String userID = cursorNew.getString(index1);
        String emailID = cursorNew.getString(index2);
        buffer.append(userID + " " + emailID + "\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Below is the code for table creation I am using. (Open to suggestions to make this less clumsy).

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tryDemoDataBase.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_USER = "user";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_GROUP = "groupseries";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 12;
    private static final String KEY_ROWID_USER = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_ROWID_EMAIL = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_ROWID_GROUP = "_id";
    private static final String REFERENCE_USER_ID = "userid";
    private static final String REFERENCE_EMAIL_ID = "emailid";
    private static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table "+ TABLE_NAME_USER
            + " ("+ KEY_ROWID_USER+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_NAME + " text)";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EMAIL = "create table "+ TABLE_NAME_EMAIL
            + " ("+ KEY_ROWID_EMAIL+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_EMAIL + " text)";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_GROUP = "create table " + TABLE_NAME_GROUP+ " ("
            + KEY_ROWID_GROUP+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + REFERENCE_USER_ID + " integer, " + REFERENCE_EMAIL_ID + " integer)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove this line:

```
cursorNew.moveToFirst();
```

because later you use:

```
while (cursorNew.moveToNext())
```

so actually you are skipping the 1st (and maybe the only) row of the results.
Then you must include in the selected columns the column `name` if you want to retrieve it from the `Cursor` object:

```
Cursor cursorNew = db.rawQuery("SELECT name, email FROM groupseries INNER JOIN email " +
            "ON groupseries.emailid = email._id INNER JOIN user ON " +
            "groupseries.userid = user._id WHERE name=" + inputData, null);
```

And a suggestion to use the recommended and safe way of passing parameters to a query instead of concatenating them directly.
Use `?` placeholders:

```
String inputData = "Vineet"; // no quotes
Cursor cursorNew = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT name, email FROM groupseries INNER JOIN email " +
            "ON groupseries.emailid = email._id INNER JOIN user ON " +
            "groupseries.userid = user._id WHERE name=?", 
             new String[] {inputData}
);
```